# How to prevent stopping the video?

Tags: javascript, youtube

In my site I've a script with a youtube' iframe.

Can I prevent to stop the video?

Comment: @mplungjan But the video can be stopped by being clicked, by selecting the pause button with arrows and releasing 'Enter' key, by releasing 'Spacebar', etc.

Comment: True... So the answer is still no

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate the controls and also make the iframe not clickable:

```css
#ytplayer {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&controls=0"
  frameborder="0"/>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WalterIT/rk593d90/